# Unable to turn on two separate lights from switches in one box

Tags: wiring

I have a box with a 3 way switch for a kitchen light.  I installed a dimmer for a new dining room light in the same box.  The power comes into a box in the attic.  All ceiling lights run from the same circuit breaker.  The kitchen light was installed prior and worked on the 3 way.  The new dimmer and light are connected with common run from the switch to the attic and connected to two common wires in the box.  The second wire from the switch is connected to the light fixture black wire.  The light's white wire is connected to the other neutral wires in the attic box.  With the power on, the kitchen light works when both switches of the 3 way are on.  The light on the dimmer does not work.  If I turn off the remote switch for the 3 way and turn on the 3 way in the box with the dimmer, the dimmer and light work but not the kitchen light.  Any ideas how to fix so I can use both the dimmer/dining room light and the kitchen light at the same time?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both switch boxes?

Comment: Since you did it, we need to know how you wired this thing.